# How to hide H1 but making sure search engines find and index its content

Tags: html, css, seo, search-engine

I have `h1` tag in a page. I do not want to display it to user but want to make sure that its content will be used for SEO. What is recommended way of achieving it these days. I can think of:

1. in css: `position absolute; left: -99999em;`
2. `display: none;`
3. `visibility: hidden;` (even though it still exists in flow of document)
4. remove `h1` with javascript when page loads

As far as I know 1,2,3 will be easily detected by Google and penalised accordingly, is that right? Would 4 be the only option not resulting in being penalised? What other options are available and safe to use?

BTW I'm not trying to trick user or search engines in any way, it just happens that `h1` is in a way and need to get rid of it.

Comment: "*it just happens that h1 is in a way and need to get rid of it.* - so get rid of it, or amend it to fit the design. Don't try looking for ways to trick search engines, because it *looks* like user-manipulation, regardless of intent.

Comment: This question is off-topic because search-engine optimisation, or adaptations to avoid search-engine penalisation, is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
h1 {
opacity: 0.0; // Sets visibility to 0%
}
```

If opacity is set to 1.0, it will be 100%.